# How to set font size and font-family in wordpress email body for entire website

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to set Calibri font at 13 points for all emails sent out automatically by the site and my website was build using wordpress. I checked the wp_mail function in wp-includes/pluggable.php file. Also I checked in wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php file. But I am not able to find the exact location to do this.

Comment: inspect the code of an email and paste it here so that we can try to help you

Comment: This is what I get when I inspect email.
<div id=":20c" class="a3s" style="overflow: hidden;">Hello,<br>
<br>
This is just a test email.

Regards,<br>
Your <span class="il">Connector</span> Team<div class="yj6qo"></div><div class="adL"><br>
</div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the core.

There is a great plugin that allows you to modify all the WP emails very easily, try it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your line of code in the `pluggable.php` file located inside `wp-includes`.

In this file you can find the email header, and as the style for the emails should be inline, what I would do is to append before the body (i think is `$message`) the inline style, something like

```
<style>
span,p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family:calibri;
font-size:13pt
}
</style>
```

I'm not sure as I didn't try it, but if you're stuck you can give it a try.

If this doesn't work you can install some plugins that will allow you to customize the default email templates